# Python's FTPLib too slow?

Tags: python, ftp, performance, dos

I have been playing around with Python's FTP library and am starting to think that it is too slow as compared to using a script file in DOS?  I run sessions where I download thousands of data files  (I think I have over 8 million right now).  My observation is that the download process seems to take five to ten times as long in Python than it does as compared to using the ftp commands in the DOS shell.

Since I don't want anyone to fix my code I have not included any.  I am more interested in understanding if my observation is valid or if I need to tinker more with the arguments.

Comment: It would be nice to see your python script and related dos batch file script for comparision.  In your python script make sure you reuse your initial connection.

Comment: The answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26314086/3273031) saying to change the default block size really helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTPLib is implemented in Python whereas your "DOS Script" is actually a script which calls a compiled command. Executing this command is probably faster than interpreting Python code. If it is too slow for you, I suggest to call the DOS command from Python using the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thanks I did now know about the subprocess module.  I have been using SAS to generate a script that I run through the shell but I would like to move everything to Python so I will study the subprocess module

Comment: The bottleneck in this can of code is certainly not in the python / C code but more likely during the network process (handshake, ping, dl; etc). This can not explain the low speed he had encountered.

Comment: @e-satis: Unlikely since he gets good performance with compiled code for a very large set of measurements.

Answer (score 4):

The speed problem is probably in your code. FTPlib is not 10 times slower.

Comment: Is it slower say I just want to download one file.  I played around and could not get it to match the speed on a 1.5 mb file

Comment: maybe it can't "match the speed" however it won't be *10 times slower*. Measure the speed difference by downloading many different sized files, either all at once or one at a time, and average the times.

Comment: @PyNEwbie: Maybe you should reconsider your decision on not posting the code, I think you're doing something stupid on it.

Comment: I agree with this suggestion.  I was doing something stupid in my code, and quick run with cProfile told me what my problem was.  In my case, it was keeping the received data in a string and the writing it out after the transfer was complete.

Answer (score 4):

define blocksize along with storbinary of ftp connection,so you will get 1.5-3.0x more faster connection than FTP Filezilla :)

```
from ftplib import FTP

USER = "Your_user_id"
PASS = "Your_password"
PORT = 21
SERVER = 'ftp.billionuploads.com' #use FTP server name here

ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect(SERVER, PORT)
ftp.login(USER, PASS)

try:
    file = open(r'C:\Python27\1.jpg','rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + '1.jpg', file,102400) #here we store file in 100kb blocksize
    ftp.quit()
    file.close()
    print "File transfered"
except:
    print "Error in File transfering"
```

Answer (score 3):

FTPlib may not be the cleanest Python API, I don't think it so bad that it run ten times slower than a DOS shell script.

Unless you do not provide any code to compare, e.g you shell and you python snippet to batch dl 5000 files, I can't see how we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I had no way of knowing what to expect

Answer (score 3):

Bigger blocksize is not always the optimum.
For example uploading the same 167 MB file through wired network to same FTP server I got following times in seconds for various blocksizes:

```
Blocksize  Time
102400       40
 51200       30
 25600       28
 32768       30
 24576       31
 19200       34
 16384       61
 12800      144
```

In this configuration the optimum was around 32768 (4x8192).

But if I used wireless instead, I got these times:

```
Blocksize  Time
204800       78
102400       76
 51200       79
 25600       76
 32768       89
 24576       86
 19200       75
 16384      166
 12800      178
default     223
```

In this case there were several optimum blocksize values, all different from 32768.

Answer (score 2):

```
import ftplib
import time
ftp = ftplib.FTP("localhost", "mph")
t0 = time.time()
with open('big.gz.sav', 'wb') as f:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + '/Temp/big.gz', f.write)
t1 = time.time()
ftp.close()
ftp = ftplib.FTP("localhost", "mph")
t2 = time.time()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + '/Temp/big.gz', lambda x: x)
t3 = time.time()
print "saving file: %f to %f: %f delta" % (t0, t1, t1 - t0)
print "not saving file: %f to %f: %f delta" % (t2, t3, t3 - t2)
```

So, maybe not 10x.  But my runs of this saving a file are all above 160s on a laptop with a core 1.8Ghz core i7 and 8GB of ram (should be overkill) running Windows 7.  A native client does it at 100s.  Without the file save I'm just under 70s.

I came to this question because I've seen slow performance with ftplib on a mac (I'll rerun this test again once I have access to that machine again).  While going async with the writes might be a good idea in this case, on a real network I suspect that would be far less of a gain.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I appreciate your insights

Answer (score 2):

disable ftplib and execute ftp via Msdos

```
os.system('FTP -v -i -s:C:\\ndfd\\wgrib2\\ftpscript.txt')
```

inside ftpscript.txt

```
open example.com
username
password
!:--- FTP commands below here ---
lcd c:\MyLocalDirectory
cd  public_html/MyRemoteDirectory
binary
mput "*.*"
disconnect
bye
```